# Right-angled triangle proof

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

> Let $ABC$ be a triangle. Points $M$ and $N$ are on the sides $AB$ and $BC$ respectively such that $\frac{BN}{BC} = \frac{2BM}{MA}$ and $\angle BNM=\angle ANC$. Prove that ABC is a right-angled triangle.

My attempted work:

[image]

$BN/BC = 2BM/MA$

$1+\frac{NC}{BN} = \left(\frac{MA}{2BM}+\frac{1}{2}\right) + \frac{1}{2}$

$2\frac{BC}{BN}= \frac{AB}{AM}+1$

I've tried to draw several auxiliary lines and still couldn't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\measuredangle BNM=\alpha$.

Thus,
$$\frac{2BM}{MA}=\frac{2S_{\Delta BMN}}{S_{\Delta AMN}}=\frac{2BN\cdot MN\sin\alpha}{AN\cdot MN\sin(180^{\circ}-2\alpha)}=\frac{BN}{AN\cos\alpha}.$$
In another hand,
$$\frac{2BM}{MA}=\frac{BN}{NC}.$$
Thus, $$NC=AN\cos\alpha.$$
Let $\measuredangle C=\gamma$.

Thus, by law of sines  for $\Delta ANC$ we obtain:
$$\cos\alpha=\frac{\sin(\alpha+\gamma)}{\sin\gamma}$$ or
$$\cos\alpha\sin\gamma=\sin\alpha\cos\gamma+\cos\alpha\sin\gamma,$$
which gives $\gamma=90^{\circ}$ and we are done!

Comment: Thank you. Please explain why, $\frac{2BM}{MC}=\frac{2S_{\Delta BMN}}{S_{\Delta AMN}}$. I understand the rest.

Comment: @carat It was typo. See now please.

Comment: I'm clear now. Thank you for your kind help.

Comment: @carat You are welcome!